# Resizing the photo by protecting the aspect ratio on Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, image-resizing, django-imagekit

How can I resize image when I upload with `ImageField` by protecting **aspect ratio** of image.

Example: (Width x Height) from **1100x600** to **550x300**

And, is it possible with `[ImageKit]` ? https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit

Comment: You don't need the library. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23936340/10860596

Answer (score 0):

You can use **easy-thumbnails** package for optimizing images.
Just follow these steps:

1. First install easy-thumbnails package using command:

   ```
   pip install easy-thumbnails
   ```
2. Go to settings.py file and add easy_thumbnails to the **INSTALLED_APPS** setting as like:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
        # ...
        'easy_thumbnails',
   ]
   ```
3. Run this command to apply changes in database

   ```
   python manage.py migrate
   ```
4. Now go to your template and replace the line(as I supposed):

   ```
   <img src="{{ image.image.url }}">
   ```

   To the following lines:

   ```
   {% load thumbnail %}

   <img src="{% thumbnail image.image 550x300 %}"
   ```